# Why am I getting error in trigger when I update salary of employee?

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc

```
create or replace TRIGGER CHECK_GRADE
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON EMPLOYEE
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    LoSal NUMBER(8, 2);
    HiSal NUMBER(8, 2);
    Letter VARCHAR(1);
    Sal NUMBER(8, 2);
BEGIN
    IF(:NEW.GLetter IS NOT NULL)
    THEN
        Sal := NVL(:NEW.Salary, -1);

        SELECT MinSalary, MaxSalary
        INTO LoSal, HiSal
        FROM GRADE
        WHERE GLetter = :NEW.GLetter;

        IF(NOT(Sal BETWEEN LoSal AND HiSal))
        THEN
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Salary does not correspond to grade error! ' );
        END IF;
    ELSIF(:NEW.Salary IS NOT NULL) 
    THEN
        SELECT GLetter
        INTO Letter
        FROM GRADE
        WHERE :NEW.Salary BETWEEN MinSalary AND MaxSalary;
        :NEW.GLetter := Letter;
    END IF;
END;
```

This is the sql statement I run
basically what I want to do is that when a user tries to update the salary of an employee the trigger will automatically fill the grade of the employee which corresponds to his/her salary

```
update employee set salary = 25500 where employeeid = 1006;
```

Table for employee
has attributes like name department name and others and salary and grade

Table for Grade has
minsalary
max salary
gradeletter

```
Error starting at line : 2 in command -
update employee set salary = 25500 where employeeid = 1006
Error report -
ORA-20001: Salary does not correspond to grade error!
ORA-06512: at "gh12345.CHECK_GRADE", line 18
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'gh12345.CHECK_GRADE'
```

Comment: I'm confused.  Your trigger code appears to pretty clearly be designed to throw an error if you try to set a salary outside the employee's grade.  The text of your question says that you want to change the grade based on the salary (are we assuming that each grade is a unique range and that there are no gaps between ranges?)  If the goal is to change the grade, why is there a `raise_application_error` call?  If the goal is to change the grade, why is there nothing that attempts to set `:new.GLetter`?

Answer (score 0):

The error is being raised because of this part here:

```
  SELECT MinSalary, MaxSalary
        INTO LoSal, HiSal
        FROM GRADE
        WHERE GLetter = :NEW.GLetter;

        IF(NOT(Sal BETWEEN LoSal AND HiSal))
        THEN
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Salary does not correspond to grade error! ' );
        END IF;
```

you are setting the salary to the value 25500 which is out of the range defined in this table `GRADE`.

So you should do a query on this table and define a value for `Salary` that is within this range, or update the `GRADE` table for your new disired range.